# Problems with simple dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Recently learned about the dynamic memory allocation in C and was trying to write a simple program that reads a bunch of words, stores them in a dynamic array and than prints words in reversed order, but i get a segmentation error on execution. Please don't be too harsh on me, I'm just learning, any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char **arr = (char **)malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
    int maxarr = 1, arrsz = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (arrsz >= maxarr)
        {
            maxarr *= 2;
            arr = (char **)realloc(arr, maxarr * sizeof(char *));
            if (!arr)
                return -1;
        }
        arr[arrsz] = (char *)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
        int i = arrsz++;
        int sz = 0, mx = 1;
        char ch = getchar();
        while (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')
        {
            if (sz >= mx)
            {
                mx *= 2;
                arr[i] = (char *)realloc(arr[i], mx * sizeof(char));
                if (!arr[i])
                    return -1;
            }
            arr[i][sz++] = ch;
            ch = getchar();
        }
        if (sz >= mx)
        {
            mx++;
            arr[i] = (char *)realloc(arr[i], mx * sizeof(char));
            if (!arr[i])
                return -1;
        }
        arr[i][sz++] = '\0';
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
    }

    for (int i = arrsz - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (arr[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s ", arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxarr; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You've got an infinite loop.  Do `int c; while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF)`.  `getchar` returns an int.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it's not infinite. It breaks when a `\n` is encountered.

Comment: @LukaSsS And what happens if the user presses the end-of-file key before entering a space or a newline? Or uses input redirection? Or a pipe?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, now i see how it could be a problem, thanks, though it is just an exercise for understanding how all the `alloc`-s work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maxarr; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
```

This is bad because the elements from `arr[arrsz]` to `arr[maxarr-1]` are uninitialized. Using values of buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized invokes *undefined behavior*.

It should be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrsz; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents :

You should always check that your `malloc` calls are successful or not.  Not only for  `realloc` calls.

After :

`char **arr = (char **)malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));`

You should add :

`if (!arr) return -1;`

Another point, for your potential `realloc` failures, try to leave with the heap in relatively good state. Instead of directly returning, you should try to clean `arr` before, as it is local and only used in your function. I suggest you to add a custom `realloc`function that will do this cleaning in case of failure, and then your main function can then directly return -1 in case of failure.